# Comparing exact values in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, compare, comparison

So this is a bit confusing. I am currently making a Top-Trumps game. Right now I have two arrays, a player deck and a computer deck. The way it works is that it creates an array from a text file of dog names, then assigns 4 values to it (Exercise, Intelligence, Friendliness and Drool). This all works. Then it splits up the deck and gives half to each array (player and computer). The user gets the first pick and I have managed to get it to allow the user to pick a category. What I don't know how to do is compare exact values in the two arrays. The arrays are listed as follows (example):

[['Fern-the-Fox-Terrier'], 'Exercise: ', 3, 'Intelligence: ', 67, 'Friendliness: ', 10, 'Drool: ', 4]

Here is the code if you need it: (I'm not sure how to attach a text file)

```
import random
import shutil
import os      #here I have imported all necessary functions for the following code to work
import array
import time

allowedresponses = ["Exercise","Intelligence","Friendliness","Drool"] #this allows me to make sure both the user and the computer select only the values available
cardcount = 0
usercards = 0           #the following variables are used for later
computercards = 0
x = 1
y = 0


play = input("Welcome to Celebrity Dogs Top Trumps! Press S to start, or Q to quit: ")
play = play.upper()
while x==1:
    if play == "S" or play == "s":
        print("Great! Lets play!")
        x+=1                                #here the user is given the option to play the game or quit. Pressing Q will immediatley end the the program, whilst pressing S will start it.
    elif play == "Q" or play == "q":        #x = 1 variable is used to end the while loop, permitted the user enters an appropriate answer
        print("OK, bye")
        quit
        x+=1
    else:
        print("That's not a valid answer. Please try again")
        play = input("Welcome to Celebrity Dogs Top Trumps! Press S to start, or Q to quit: ")

cardcount = int(input("How many cards in this game? Please pick an even number between 4 and 30: "))  #the following section of code asks the to select the number of cards they want played
while x==2:
    if cardcount < 4:
        print("Thats too small! Please try again!") #the programs tells the user to select again if they have picked a number smaller than 4
        cardcount = int(input("How many cards in this game? Please pick an even number between 4 and 30: "))
    elif cardcount > 30:
        print("Thats too big! Please try again!") #the programs tells the user to select again if they have picked a number larger than 30
        cardcount = int(input("How many cards in this game? Please pick an even number between 4 and 30: "))
    if cardcount % 2 != 0:
        print("Thats an odd number! Please try again!")#the programs tells the user to select again if they have picked a number that can't be divided by 2 with no remainders, essentially forcing only even numbers
        cardcount = int(input("How many cards in this game? Please pick an even number between 4 and 30: "))
    else:
        print("Perfect! Onwards!")
        x+=1 #once again I have used the x variable to allow the user to continue if they have selected a number that fits the requirements

time.sleep(1)

print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")

print("Rules: 1) For exercise, intelligence and friendliness, the highest value wins. For drool, lowest wins")
print("       2) If there is a draw, the player that picked the value wins and gets the cards")
shutil.copyfile('dogs.txt','celebdogs.txt') #this creates a copy of the dogs text file. It is mainly for if I ever need to edit a file with the dogs in,, the origin file is never changed.

topdogs = [] #here I have created an array for the dogs 
inp = open('celebdogs.txt','r') #I have used python's text file edits to import everything in the newly made celebdogs text file into an array, in order to import it later
for line in inp.readlines():
    topdogs.append([])
    for i in line.split():
        topdogs[-1].append(i)
inp.close()

deck = [] #here I have created an array for the deck of cards that will be used in the game

print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")

for index in range(0,cardcount): #this part of the code tells the program to repeat the following until the number of cards selected by the user is in the deck
    deck.insert([index][0], [(random.choice(topdogs))])#h
    deck[index].append("Exercise: ")
    deck[index].append(random.randint(0,5))
    deck[index].append("Intelligence: ")
    deck[index].append(random.randint(0,100))
    deck[index].append("Friendliness: ")
    deck[index].append(random.randint(0,10))
    deck[index].append("Drool: ")
    deck[index].append(random.randint(0,10))

time.sleep(1)

playerDeck=[]
computerDeck=[]

while len(deck)>0:
    playerDeck.append(deck.pop(0))
    computerDeck.append(deck.pop(0))

time.sleep(1)

print("This is your deck: ")
print(playerDeck)

playerTurn = True

print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")

time.sleep(1)

print("This is your first card: ")
print(playerDeck[0])

if playerTurn == True:
    answer = input("Please select an attack (Exercise, Intelligence, Friendliness and Drool): ")
    while allowedresponses.count(answer) == 0:
        answer = input("That isn't a valid choice, please try again: ")

else:
    answer = random.choice(allowedresponses)
    print("Computer chooses", answer)

print("Computer Card: ")
print(computerDeck[0])


if playerDeck == cardcount:
    print("You win!!!!")

if computerDeck == cardcount:
    print("Computer wins!!!!")

os.remove('celebdogs.txt')
```

Just in case I haven't explained this well, I need help knowing how to compare precise values in two arrays, so if I want to compare the values of Exercise in both decks for the single cards. Both arrays have the exact same format (name, exercise, value, intelligence, value, friendliness, value, drool, value) so I need to be able to compare specific values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try use python's `zip` function:

```
computerDeck = [1, 2, 3]
playerDeck = [1, 3, 3]

for computer_card, player_card in zip(computerDeck, playerDeck):
    if computer_card == player_card:
        print('valid')
    else:
        print('invalid')
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the help. Just because I want to try to understand, what does the i do. Referring to the ai, bi part. Thanks!                                                                                   EDIT: Sorry mate, didn't work. Not sure if I used it wrong but it just compares overall. I need to be able to compare specific elements in both arrays. Both arrays have the exact same format (name, exercise, value, intelligence, value, friendliness, value, drool, value) so I need to be able to compare specific values

Comment: @RaviPatel i've changed code for you case. This code valid if you want to compare every card in two decks.

Comment: @RaviPatel, python zip is basically maps the two lists with their index that is,
`playerDeck = [6, 7, 8]`
`computerDeck = [1, 2, 3]` so
`zip(computerDeck, playerDeck)` will be 
`[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8)]`

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran is it possible to select which elements I want to compare exactly? Based on user choice

Comment: you say, you want to compare specific index or a dictionary key?

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran I want to compare a specific index I believe. Not going to lie not 100% but more 90%

Comment: @RaviPatel you want to get some choice from user and check it in two lists?

Comment: @RezvanovMaxim You've got it spot on mate. So the user selects the value and then it is that value's number is compared on both cards. So if Exercise is selected and the user' is 7 whilst the computer's is 6, the user would win

Comment: @RaviPatel hmmm, exercise? Im not native english speaker. Can't understand this sentense :)